# What format input geometry needs to have to be able search by geometry/bbox?

Tags: arcgis

I'm trying to filter data here, by specific USA state - https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nhd/MapServer/12/query
However, I'm not sure how to use the "Input Geometry" field (in which format geometry needs to be).
Could someone send me an example with polygon applied as a one filter AND in `Where` there will be `"FCODE"=46006` filter as well?

Answer (score 0):

For input geometry you need to provide a valid geometry object in JSON format, as specified by ESRI: [enter link description here](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/geometry-objects.htm)

Within the JSON you can specify type of geometry (point, poly etc) as well as spatial reference in wkid or wkt format.

```
 {
  "xmin": -109.55,
  "ymin": 25.76,
  "xmax": -86.39,
  "ymax": 49.94,
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 4326
  }
}
```

Finally, the ArcGIS REST API documentation explains what other parameters to pass to your HTTP GET verb to specify the 'where' clause.

Here is an example call to your service: [https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nhd/MapServer/12/query?where=FCODE=46006&geometry={](https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nhd/MapServer/12/query?where=FCODE=46006&geometry=%7B)
"xmin": -180,
"ymin": -90,
"xmax": 180,
"ymax": 90,
"spatialReference": {
"wkid": 4326
}
}&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&f=pjson